# How do I find the output of a tensor and/or op in tensorflow? (or "tensorflow op.outputs only pointing to itself")

Tags: python, tensorflow

First things first - this might be a very basic and dumb question, but I've tried many things and searched all over to no avail, so here I am.
The problem is the following:
I have a tensor, and I'd like to find "where it leads" for various reasons.
The way to theoretically do this would be to just look at my_tensor.op.outputs, as per documentation and such, but **this always seems to point back to my_tensor** itself!
I've easily gone the other way before, meaning I can get the input tensor by using my_tensor.op.inputs, but for some reason "outputs" isn't doing the expected.
Here's a simple example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8, name='a')
b = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8, name='b')
my_sum = tf.identity(a + b, name='my_sum')
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

# I should have 4 ops at this point, as validated by:
print(graph.get_operations())
>> [<tf.Operation 'a' type=Placeholder>, <tf.Operation 'b' type=Placeholder>, <tf.Operation 'add' type=Add>, <tf.Operation 'my_sum' type=Identity>]

# So let's try get the output of 'a':
print(list(a.op.outputs))
>> [<tf.Tensor 'a:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=uint8>]
```

If you tried the above, you'll see you got back to 'a'...
Again, running my_sum.op.inputs gives the 'add' op, and running even further back get's us to 'a' and 'b' as expected:

```
input_to_my_sum = list(my_sum.op.inputs)[0]
print(input_to_my_sum)
>> Tensor("add:0", dtype=uint8)

print(list(input_to_my_sum.op.inputs))
>> [<tf.Tensor 'a:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=uint8>, <tf.Tensor 'b:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=uint8>]
```

But the other way round? No such luck:

```
print(list(input_to_my_sum.op.outputs))
>> [<tf.Tensor 'add:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=uint8>]

print('This is no fun at all')
>> This is no fun at all
```

So **what am I doing wrong?**
I've also tried using the (deprecated) op.values() with no success, and I'm confused because the documentation explicitly states that this should give me the outputs of the op (from https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation):

> outputs
>   The list of Tensor objects representing the outputs of this op.

(I checked that a.op.__class__ is the right class and that I'm reading the correct documentation).

(Just to wrap things up, the node_def of the ops also shows no signs of an output field...).
Thanks in advance for any advice!

---

Edit (due to Yuxin's answer):
Just to clarify, taking the output of the output of the etc. stays put on the same tensor. I'm trying to reach the *next* tensor/op.

P.S: This is my first stackoverflow question, so if I did anything "wrong" let me know and I'll try fix it.

Comment: I am not sure what you are expecting, but do remember that setting up the operations graph and executing operations are different things in tensorflow. If you were expecting to see the actual value of the sum, you will not, you need to run the graph operations in a session first.

Comment: No, I get that. I wasn't looking for a value of course, nor anything else that requires a session or feeding anything into the tensors or anything similar. See the accepted answer for what I was (unfortunately not) getting at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and I'm confused because the documentation explicitly states that this should give me the outputs of the op

It does give you the output of the op:

```
print(list(input_to_my_sum.op.outputs))
>> [<tf.Tensor 'add:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=uint8>]
```

So I'm not sure what you're confused about or what you're expecting.

Be sure to understand the concept of "Tensor" and "Operation". In a tensorflow graph, an Operation
takes a list of input Tensors and outputs a list of Tensors.
In Python, you can `print(x)` to see if `x` is a Tensor or Operation.

Operation has `.inputs` (which are Tensors) and `.outputs` (which are Tensors).
Tensor does not have inputs and outputs. Tensor has `.op`, which is the Operation that produces it as outputs.
Tensor also has `.consumers()`, which is a list of Operations which take the Tensor as inputs.

`input_to_my_sum` is a Tensor, the result of the Add.
`input_to_my_sum.op` is a Operation, the Add Operation that produces the result `input_to_my_sum`.
Therefore `input_to_my_sum.op.outputs` contains `input_to_my_sum`.

Comment: Well, I suspect that due to 'add' being the _input_ to 'my_sum', then the _output_ of 'add' should be 'my_sum'. No? (Try taking the output of the output of the output of...1000 times. you stay put on the same tensor...)

Comment: I think you need to understand "Tensor" vs "Operation". The Tensor `my_sum` is the output of the operation Identity. The input to the operation Identity is the Tensor called c = a + b. The Tensor c is the output of an operation "add".

Comment: Ok, I'll read up about that. But how do I get the next node of a tensor or an op if not via the outputs attribute? (Note the asymmetry with the inputs attribute)

Comment: list(my_sum.op.outputs)[0] == my_sum returns True. For every tensor I've ever tried. Is _outputs_ that useless??

Comment: A Tensor has `.consumers()` which contains a list of Operations whose `.inputs` contain the Tensor. An Operation has `outputs` which contains a list of Tensors whose `.op` is the Operation.  `outputs` and `inputs` are not meant to be symmetric like the way you imagine.

Comment: `list(my_sum.op.outputs)[0] == my_sum` will not be true if `my_sum.op` is a Operation which has more than one outputs, and `my_sum` is not the first of those outputs.

Comment: I dug in a bit with the help of your comments, and I see now where I was going wrong and how to do things correctly. Do you want to flesh out and/or make your answer a little clearer apropos this discussion so I can accept it?

Comment: And I've accepted :-)
Thanks a million. Oh, and keep it up with TensorPack. It's the best I've worked with.